# what does delay loading mean?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a webpage and between the pages

**NOTE: it's not a single-page website**

I made transitions using `transform: TranslateX()` or `transform: TranslateY()`, my friend told me it delays loading.

here's what it looks like [the gif](https://gyazo.com/77b927e1e42333482130b51f4550ab52)
(sorry for the hebrew)

my question is, what does loading delay mean? and is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do?